# A way to mark notification as seen without reading the notification feed?

Tags: getstream-io

My situation is the following:
I'm using the stream-js library. I add entries to the notification feeds of users for certain events - comments, follows, etc. After I write to their feed I also send a push notification to that user's device.

If a user clicks on a push notification I want to be able to mark the corresponding activity as seen. There's currently no way to do that since the  `add` or `addToMany` calls do not return the ids of the added activities for me to send in the notification payload.

Ideally I'd want a way to mark a notification feed item as seen either by an activity group id or by some other unique id (or the `foreignId`). Is there a way to do that? If not, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Two parts to this answer:

## Getting the ID of an activity that you just added

The `addActivity` call in the various Stream client libraries (I'm using `stream-js` in this case) will return back the created activity, which should include the activity ID. Response looks something like this:

```
{ 
  actor: 'ken',
  duration: '9.65ms',
  foreign_id: '',
  id: '8b5d69a9-8b73-11e8-98ab-12cb9e7b86a4',
  object: 'some-object',
  origin: null,
  target: '',
  time: '2018-07-19T16:48:21.045496',
  verb: 'add-activity' 
}
```

## Marking notification feed items as seen or read

The way to mark a notification feed item as seen or read is a little funky - first, you get the feed, like you would normally do, but you'll also pass in the `mark_seen` or `mark_read` options. (`true` will mark all items as seen or read, and an array of activity **group** IDs will mark only those items.)

From that call, the notification feed will be returned *without* the items marked as seen or read - but the *next* call to retrieve the notification feed will have the items marked accordingly.

More docs on that here: https://getstream.io/docs/flat_feeds/#notification_feeds

### activity ID `-->` activity group ID

You might have noticed that you get the activity ID when adding the activity, but you need to pass in the activity **group** ID when marking items seen or read.

All notification feeds are actually aggregated feeds as well - by default, the aggregation format that they use is just the activity ID, which means that there will be only one activity per activity group, and the **activity group ID will be the same as the activity ID**. So, you can just use the activity ID returned by the `addActivity` call to get the notification feed and mark that activity group as seen or read.

If you're not using the default aggregation format (e.g., the activity group ID is *not* the same as the activity ID), then you'll likely have to retrieve the notification feed and grab the necessary activity group ID from there.

Comment: Hi Ken - thanks for this answer. I'm mainly using the `addToMany` call when adding notification activities, though, and I noticed that one doesn't return anything besides how long the call took.

I really don't want to switch to using `addActivity` since I am potentially populating many feeds at once so it's impractical. Seems to me the way to go to mark a single activity as seen is:
Send unique activity id to server -> fetch the notification feed -> Find matching id ->  do another get call to mark that activity as read.

seems inefficient but I guess there's no other way?